# What happens when I send autorelease or retain message to autorelease pool?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iphone application development.I have doubt that What happens when I send autorelease or retain message to autorelease pool?

```
 NSAutoreleasePool  *autoRelease =[ [[ NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
NSAutoreleasePool  *autoRelease =[ [[ NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init] retain];
```

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned in the NSAutoreleasePool documentation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do either of those things, it raises an exception. You should not do them.